# How to indicate required properties for an object for swagger-ui

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have simple CXF-REST application for which for one of the services', I have an object as input. One of the parameters are mandatory for successful validation, however, swagger-ui shows optional or empty.

How to update it to show 'required' or a star mark ?

I tried using `@ApiModelProperty(required=true)`, however no luck.

```java
@Path("/user")
@Api(value = "/user", description = "User Service")
public interface UserService {

    @POST
    @Path("/saveUser")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Save User details to backend", response = User.class)
    public User saveUser(User user);
}


@ApiModel(description = "User")
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "", required = true)
    private String name;

    private Integer age;
    //getters and setters
}
```

We use `swagger-annotations_2.10-1.3.0.jar`,
`swagger-core_2.10-1.3.0.jar`,
`swagger-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.0.jar` in our application.

ScreenShot is in the link below

[Swagger-required-properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izfT6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swagger-ui.js javascript file can be updated as below, so that the 'required' string can appear in the model section for the specified attribute.

```
  if(!propertyIsRequired) {
       html += ', <span class="propOptKey">optional</span>';
  } else {
       html += ', <span class="propOptKey">required</span>';
  }
```